# What is the difference between 搾る and 絞る?

Tags: pragmatics

According to JMDict both 搾る and 絞る mean **squeeze**.  Is there a difference in their usage? I noticed that 搾る is used to describe the process of beer making, can 絞る be used alternatively in this case?

Comment: http://chigai-allguide.com/%E7%B5%9E%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E6%90%BE%E3%82%8B/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- 搾る = milking, squeeze,
- 絞る = wring something dry out, narrow down, (voice/volume of audio) turn down, squeeze

When you squeeze a lemon 絞る and 搾る are both right.

When you say, Turn the radio down ラジオの音量を**絞る**

When you say, To get milk from cow 牛乳を**搾る**

Answer (score 1):

搾る = squeeze

絞る = squeeze + twist

e.g.

- 乳搾り
- 雑巾絞り